# Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 1 (SonarQube)

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube, sonar-runner

In sonar.log file I got this

```
2023.08.15 21:14:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\Users\archive\Downloads\sonarqube-10.0.0.68432\sonarqube-10.0.0.68432\temp
2023.08.15 21:14:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:57462]
2023.08.15 21:14:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [C:\Users\archive\Downloads\sonarqube-10.0.0.68432\sonarqube-10.0.0.68432\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java -Xms4m -Xmx64m -XX:+UseSerialGC -Dcli.name=server -Dcli.script=./bin/elasticsearch -Dcli.libs=lib/tools/server-cli -Des.path.home=C:\Users\archive\Downloads\sonarqube-10.0.0.68432\sonarqube-10.0.0.68432\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\Users\archive\Downloads\sonarqube-10.0.0.68432\sonarqube-10.0.0.68432\temp\conf\es -Des.distribution.type=tar -cp C:\Users\archive\Downloads\sonarqube-10.0.0.68432\sonarqube-10.0.0.68432\elasticsearch\lib\*;C:\Users\archive\Downloads\sonarqube-10.0.0.68432\sonarqube-10.0.0.68432\elasticsearch\lib\cli-launcher\* org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher
2023.08.15 21:14:19 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2023.08.15 21:14:22 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 1
2023.08.15 21:14:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
2023.08.15 21:14:22 ERROR app[][o.s.a.p.EsManagedProcess] Failed to check status
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2695)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2171)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2137)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2105)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.ClusterClient.health(ClusterClient.java:151)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.getClusterHealthStatus(EsConnectorImpl.java:64)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkStatus(EsManagedProcess.java:92)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:84)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.isOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:62)
    at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler.refreshState(ManagedProcessHandler.java:223)
    at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler$EventWatcher.run(ManagedProcessHandler.java:288)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1048)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.get(BaseFuture.java:243)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture.get(BaseFuture.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2692)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
2023.08.15 21:14:22 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

I have checked everything was working fine usually when I restart it use to work but now I have other Jobs running behind,So give solution to debug & solve this issue ,If anyone has faced the same issue please attach the PMR in Here ...

In es.log file I got this...

```
2023.08.15 20:52:57 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Elasticsearch] fatal exception while booting Elasticsearch
java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!
class: com.ibm.db2.jcc.licenses.DB2J
jar1: C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar
jar2: C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar
    at org.elasticsearch.jdk.JarHell.checkClass(JarHell.java:315) ~[elasticsearch-core-8.6.1.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.jdk.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:233) ~[elasticsearch-core-8.6.1.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.jdk.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-core-8.6.1.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.initPhase2(Elasticsearch.java:180) ~[elasticsearch-8.6.1.jar:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:66) ~[elasticsearch-8.6.1.jar:?]
```

Comment: There should be a log file for the embedded Elasticsearch server in the logs folder. Can you check it out? Also the heap size is really low `-Xms4m -Xmx64m`

Comment: sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx512m -Xms128m
default heap size is 512MB

Comment: I have added es.log in above

Comment: There you go: `jar hell!` prevents ES from starting

Comment: @Val can you explain in details, I didn't get it